# Android: Hide Imageview

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a imageveiw initially it should be in hidden mode,

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/custom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"    
    android:src="@drawable/custom1" />
```

and I created a login page ..whenever my login is successful I should show the image.

Comment: When login success - ImageView image.setVisibility(View.Visible)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Try this

Your xml

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/custom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"    
            android:src="@drawable/custom1" />
```

You can set here on xml like this

```
android:visibility="visible"
```

or

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

or

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Java program

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.custom);
```

set your `ImageView` like this

```
imgView .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

imgView .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

imgView .setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Difference between `INVISIBLE` and `GONE`.

`INVISIBLE` - The widget will be invisible but space for the widget will be shown.

`GONE` - Both space and widget is invisible.

Comment: initially when the app started i can see the image ..i want to hide it...how to do tht

Comment: and later wen i login i need to show tht icon..i have loginactivity for this feature only not for the whole app

Comment: @teekib Include this on your xml

android:visibility="invisible"

Comment: getting force close...i think login is different activity..and the image should be show on different activity..so geeting forceclose?

Comment: @teekib check this for button u given as "Login" and in onClickListener you gave "btnLogin".setOnClickListener

Comment: @teekib put like this Login.setOnClickListener

Comment: still ..unfortunately stopped....getting error here in log:  imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19584/discussion-between-android-apple-and-teekib)

Answer (score 12):

Set Visibility property of Imageview like this in **java**

```
imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
imgView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
imgView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Or like this in **XML**

```
android:visibility="visible"
android:visibility="invisible"
android:visibility="gone"
```

Or like this in **C#**

```
imgView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
imgView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
imgView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
```

Result for each will be like this

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Initially to set the image view to hidden mode, try

```
imageview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

and when login is successfull, change its visiblity to VISIBLE,

```
imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: You might want to use View.GONE instead of View.INVISIBLE, depending on your layout...

Comment: Yes we can, but in this particular case, OP just wants to hide and show the imageview.