# Android chart library that's able to generate a PNG without showing the chart before that

Tags: android, charts, offline

Let's start with why do I want to do that: 
The project my company's currently working in, involves the possibility to have one of our client's employee to go to the end of the world, with absolutely no way of having a connection to a mobile network, taking a portable printer with him, and print a report from his tablet. We currently have a working report already being printed this way, but they added a little detail that caused lots of trouble, which is the reason I'm here, I need to put 3 charts at the end of a Jasper report.

In a web application that would be extremely easy, since Jasper itself offer this functionallity, but since it's a mobile project, we tried using PDFReporter. This API generates a PDF from a .jrxml file, but it doesn't support every single feature from Jasper, and charts are one of them. Searching the web I've found that we could export a chart to a PNG and then add it to the report, which would work with PDFReporter.

Starting today by 8am I've spent my day searching and testing different chart-generating APIs, just to discover that, so far, 100% of the android APIs are meant to generate a chart directly on a view you specified on your activity, but that doesn't work for me at all.

I've also tested a few Java APIs, but got an issue there too, since most of them use java.awt resources to manipulate images, and that package is not included in android's SDK, nor is it supported (discovered that by adding JFreeChart to my project, which made my build take about 15 minutes and in the end fail with an OOM error).

So what I need help with is: is there an API I can use directly on a mobile project, with no connection whatsoever, that generates a pie chart as a PNG without having to render it on a view and just then fetching the Image?

I'd just like to make it clear that I'm NOT 100% sure about most of the things I've said above, except for the limitations of PDFReporter, those are confirmed, so please, any kind of help will be GREATLY appreciated, even a little "that's not how it works" will help.

Thanks in advance if you at least took your time reading it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you say "... generate a chart directly on a view you specified on your activity, but that doesn't work for me at all". Everything you see of your Android app is in some View anyway (in your case it would probably be an ImageView).

Do you just want to generate the chart as a PNG in memory and store it or manipulate it further? In that case, you could first generate it in a hidden ImageView using the API of your choice, then extract it using ImageView.getDrawable() for example. Assuming the API has no problem with the view being hidden. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397709/android-hide-imageview) helps

Comment: Hello mkoe, the fact is I'm on an activity with a recycler view, long clicking one of the items, shows up the option for you to print the report, so, yeah, putting a hidden ImageView below the recyclerView, rendering the image on it and then getting it again might be a workaround, but it's definitely something I would like to avoid...
Also, nope, don't want to manipulate, get it, save as PNG and pass it as a parameter to the report.

Comment: Two points: first, I do not know of any chart-rendering API's myself, but it is hard to imagine they do not provide methods for rendering to off-screen bitmaps (since I suppose behind the scenes they render to a bitmap anyway, then attach it to a View). I take your word for it of course, but maybe you missed such a method? Second, what I mention is essentially just rendering to an off-screen bitmap, so no reason to be uncomfortable with this "workaround", there does not seem any significant cost in speed or memory to me.

Comment: Wasn't able to check on the question earlier, anyway, in fact the only way I was able to recover the bitmap was putting not a "visibility='gone' " view, but actually one that doesn't show on screen, but is still rendered off it (below a "fill_parent" ScrollView). Not the prettiest implementation I've seen, but it works, actually it's performance is not bad at all.