# ImageView hiding and showing

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview

I'm struggling to get my android app to show and hide imageView objects programmatically. Actually I'm struggling to get expected behavior from imageView objects full stop.

Following the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397709/android-hide-imageview#_=_),

Here's what I'm testing with:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ImageView warn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.gpsStatusWarning);

    warn.setImageResource(R.drawable.gps_error);
    warn.getLayoutParams().height = 64;
    warn.getLayoutParams().width = 64;
}

}
```

The above code is called in the parent activity's OnCreate method, and it does exactly what I expect: It changes the image of the object to be the one designated, and it sets the height and width of said object. However, what I can't seem to do is to set the object as INVISIBLE or GONE. I just can't make it vanish at all, in fact. I've tried both:

```
    warn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    warn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

But the image is still visible. I've even tried changing it in the XML to

```
    android:visibility="gone"
```

But even that hasn't helped. The image is still visible.

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing a call to some update method? Does setting the image resource force the image to be drawn?

Comment: You should post more of the relevant code. That will help people see the whole picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

`warn.setImageResource(0);`

Or : `warn.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);`

Comment: Thanks for the response, both of these worked! But I was perhaps more interested in discovering why the visibility settings didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you set the visibility of `ImageView` objects on Android programatically:

```
yourImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
yourImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
yourImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

You can also set the initial states of `ImageView` objects in XML layout files like this:

```
visibility="visible"
visibility="gone"
visibility="invisible"
```

You can follow the official documentation about `ImageView` controls to try it on yourself on this link below. [Learn how to set the visibility state of a view.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)

Comment: Hi mrisek. Please read the question before responding. Thanks :)

Comment: I posted you reply with two ways how I usually set the visibility and documentation link. Hope it helped you to learn why your code didn't work at first place. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);