# Is it possible to block screen capture on certain parts of the screen?

Tags: java, android, security, screen-capture

To disable screen capturing we can use:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Is possible to use something similar to hide views?

For example:

> [imageview]
>
> [hidden content]
>
> [text view]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Hide Imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397709/android-hide-imageview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.

The system-supplied solution, `FLAG_SECURE`, is by window, not by `View`. Most views draw only in the activity's window. Some views conditionally use a second window, such as the drop-down of a `Spinner`, but you do not control those windows either.

In principle, if the views that you wanted to block from screenshots were contiguous, you could set up your own window, put the views in that window, and use `FLAG_SECURE` only on that window. This is likely to be complex and is likely to cause other sorts of problems (e.g., multi-window devices, accessibility).