# How to Imageview hide when url is empty

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-imageview, picasso

I have a Imageview its load image from Firebase Database url with Picasso Image loader. I wish to hide imageview when firebase database url is empty. How to set Imageview setVisibility gone in that time.

My code is

```
        LoadData(categoryId);


}

    private void LoadData(String categoryId) {

        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<TrollModel>().setQuery(MCC,TrollModel.class).build();
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<TrollModel, TrollViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TrollViewHolder trollViewHolder, int i, @NonNull TrollModel trollModel) {

                trollViewHolder.thrillername.setText(trollModel.getTitle());
                Picasso.get().load(trollModel.getImage())
                        .into(trollViewHolder.thrillersimage);


                trollViewHolder.setItemClickListner(new ItemClickListner() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {

                Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(TrollActivity.this, TrollDetailActivity.class);
                detailsIntent.putExtra("CategoryId", adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                startActivity(detailsIntent);


            }
                });

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public TrollViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.troll_items, parent, false);

                return new TrollViewHolder(v);
            }
        };

        adapter.startListening();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397709/android-hide-imageview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `setVisibility()` funciton for every `View` in android. You can find this if you google it in right way.

Refer below code to solve your problem.

```
if (trollModel.getImage().isEmpty()) {
   trollViewHolder.thrillersimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
   trollViewHolder.thrillersimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   Picasso.get().load(trollModel.getImage())
                        .into(trollViewHolder.thrillersimage);
}
```